# Jest jest.mock function with different return value

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

testing react and typescript with jest and enzyme, how would I mock this expectsVideo function such that I can define if it returns true of false based on my test case scenerio

```
jest.mock('utils/media-utils', () => ({
  expectsVideo: () => true,
  myOtherFunctions: jest.fn()
}));
```

the utils/media-utils if a file that is being imported in the react component that I am testing. If I try to reference object from outside it gives me error stating cannot use out of scope variables.
Tried various implementation i came across different blogs but no help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mockImplementation` should help while [mocking whole module](https://medium.com/@rickhanlonii/understanding-jest-mocks-f0046c68e53c#af80):

```
import * as mediaUtils from 'utils/media-utils';

mock('utils/media-utils'); // automocking whole module

it('....1...', () => {
    mediaUtils.expectsVideo.mockImplementation(() => true);
});

it('....2...', () => {
    mediaUtils.expectsVideo.mockImplementation(() => false);
});
```

BTW as for referencing variables from outer that returns error(from section for [`jest.doMock` documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/zh-Hans/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options)):

> When using babel-jest, calls to mock will automatically be hoisted to the top of the code block. Use this method if you want to explicitly avoid this behavior.

So that's why all `const` and `let` are not even defined at point when module is mocked.